# Creating a Polygon in r -- without connected vertices

Tags: r, polygon

I am trying to create a polygon out of this line graph -- is it possible to do without having connected vertices? If so, how do I change the polygon code to do so?

[image]

Comment: what's your expected output, exactly?

Comment: My hope is to create a polygon inbetween the line graphs and then find the area of the polygon. Doing this at different timepoints to find the amount of chlorophyll uptake by a restored oyster reef, before and after the restoration. I apologize, I am new to R (as well as this site) and don't quite know all the terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the reason you what to create a polygon is to shade or color within its boundaries. If I'm wrong about that assumption then you really should put more effort into making your questions explicit. The trick is to connect at the ends of those lines by putting them both in one vectors, at the same time as reversing the X and Y for one of the series.

```
  x <- 1:100
 y1=6 + rnorm(100)
 y2 = rnorm(100)
plot(x, y1, ylim=c(-3,10) )
 ?polygon
 polygon(x= c( x, rev(x) ), y=c(y1,rev(y2) ), col="red")
```

[image]